# How to include exposed filter name in views data feed export CSV title?

Tags: views, tokens

Trying to get views data export to save file with selected token from exposed filter

In the settings I can see this explanation:

%exposed == effective exposed filters, like filter1_foo-filter2_bar

So I tried this:

```
%[field_industry_type].csv                    
%field_industry_type.csv
%field_industry_type_tid.csv
```

But can't get nothing to work, what I'm trying to do is use a field filter as .csv name, one of the filter types is industry, so if industry is "relocation" I would like the file to save like this:

relocation.csv

Maybe my token syntax is wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

%exposed itself combination of the number of exposed filters you have on your view. When you save file name only with %exposed.csv it should generate file name as per your request would be like "industry_relocation.csv".

So, %exposed will generate based on "FIELDIDENTIFIERNAME_VALUE-ANOTHERFIELD_VALUE".

To generate a custom file name you should use hook_views_pre_build() function. You can find examples here: https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export/issues/1288612

Comment: "When you save file name only with %exposed.csv it should generate file name as per your request would be like "industry_relocation.csv" ---- That doesn't work

Comment: Your data export view must have exposed filters enabled which you have added in the page. Once you enable, use filename %exposed.csv should work.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work, I don't think %exposed.csv is the proper syntax. What do they mean by this: "effective exposed filters, like filter1_foo-filter2_bar" separate filters with underscore?

Comment: "effective exposed filters, like filter1_foo-filter2_bar" here is the explaination based on my understanding. 
filter1_foo: filter1 = Exposed filter 1 field name where foo = Exposed filter 1 field value
filter2_bar: filter2 = Exposed filter 2 field name where bar = Exposed filter 2 field value

Comment: Thanks Kirt, but still I don't understand...let's say the exposed filter is called "industry" and the value is "dental", I want the file to be saved as dental.csv, what would be the exact syntax or verbose to put in there?

Comment: Hi there, I am not sure where you stuck. However, the above explanation works in my D7 view.